# YouTube GData API - Query for videos with a specific duration

Tags: youtube, gdata, duration

Is there a YouTube GData API parameter for a query that will only return entries with a minimum and/or a maximum given duration?
I've found the "duration" parameter but it only accepts the values "short", "medium", and "long".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it!

You need to integrate such query conditions into the ***fields*** parameter, which operates on a syntax similar to xpath:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?fields=entry[*videoVariable* operator *value*]
```

So for what I was looking for, the *fields* parameter value would have been:

```
entry[media:group/yt:duration/@seconds > *min_value* and media:group/yt:duration/@seconds < *max_value*]
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Gdata for Objective - C?