# Way to get more than 999 results from a Youtube video feed?

Tags: java, video, youtube, youtube-api, feed

I'm writing right now a bachelorthesis about the Long Tail and want to get data to research it's behaviour. That's why I wanted to retrieve information on the viewcounts of youtube videos. The only problem is that one video feed to a specific topic like "most_popular" has only 999 entries. Is there a way to retrieve more data to a specific category or in general? I'll post my current code (it's a try to retrieve data for the category  "sports") here:

```
public static void printVideoEntry(VideoEntry videoEntry, boolean detailed) {
      System.out.println("Title: " + videoEntry.getTitle().getPlainText());

      if(videoEntry.isDraft()) {
        System.out.println("Video is not live");
        YtPublicationState pubState = videoEntry.getPublicationState();
        if(pubState.getState() == YtPublicationState.State.PROCESSING) {
          System.out.println("Video is still being processed.");
        }
        else if(pubState.getState() == YtPublicationState.State.REJECTED) {
          System.out.print("Video has been rejected because: ");
          System.out.println(pubState.getDescription());
          System.out.print("For help visit: ");
          System.out.println(pubState.getHelpUrl());
        }
        else if(pubState.getState() == YtPublicationState.State.FAILED) {
          System.out.print("Video failed uploading because: ");
          System.out.println(pubState.getDescription());
          System.out.print("For help visit: ");
          System.out.println(pubState.getHelpUrl());
        }
      }

      if(videoEntry.getEditLink() != null) {
        System.out.println("Video is editable by current user.");
      }

      if(detailed) {



        YtStatistics stats = videoEntry.getStatistics();
        if(stats != null ) {
          System.out.println("View count: " + stats.getViewCount());
        }
        System.out.println();


      }
    }

  public static void printVideoFeed(VideoFeed videoFeed, boolean detailed) {
      for(VideoEntry videoEntry : videoFeed.getEntries() ) {
        printVideoEntry(videoEntry, detailed);
      }
    } 

  public static void printEntireVideoFeed(YouTubeService service, 
          VideoFeed videoFeed, boolean detailed) throws MalformedURLException, 
          IOException, ServiceException {
         do {
           printVideoFeed(videoFeed, detailed);
           if(videoFeed.getNextLink() != null) {
             videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(videoFeed.getNextLink().getHref()), 
               VideoFeed.class);
           }
           else {
             videoFeed = null;
           }
         }
         while(videoFeed != null);
        }


  public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

      YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("test");

      YouTubeQuery query = 
              new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));
            query.setFullTextQuery("Sports");
            VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
            printEntireVideoFeed(service, videoFeed, false);
  }
  catch(AuthenticationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(ServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the [YouTube Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API) and/or the [YouTube Analytics API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API)?

Comment: I am just using the Youtube Data API for retrieving the data. I thing the  Analytics API was just to analyze your own videos and channel (or other user's videos and channels) not videos in general wasn't it?

Comment: Could you give links to the jar files you use? I've tried gdata-youtube-1.0.jar (61.533 bytes) and gdata-youtube-2.0.jar (119.923 bytes), but the `VideoEntry` class does not have a `getTitle` method? The latest V3 API (google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev21-1.13.2-beta.jar - 91.114 bytes) does not have a `VideoEntry` class?
The analytics part (btw, my previous link is wrong) is for retrieving your YouTube analytics reports, so I think that's not the one you want.

Comment: I was using the gdata jar files provided on this site:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list

and i got the code for paginating the video feed from here: 

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Pagination

I hope this will help. Thank you for thinking this through!

Comment: I've solved my issue with the `VideoEntry` class: it inherits the `getTitle` method from the `BaseEntry` class, which is in gdata-core-1.0.jar. After adding more jars to my project, your code above works fine. I now use these jars: activation.jar, gdata-base-1.0.jar, gdata-client-1.0.jar, gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar, gdata-core-1.0.jar, gdata-media-1.0.jar, gdata-youtube-2.0.jar, gdata-youtube-meta-2.0.jar, guava-r07.jar and mail.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The 999 entries appears to be a limit by design. See the [YouTube API v2.0 – Video Feed Types](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds):

> "The API returns a videos feed in response to a request to search for videos. A videos feed contains a maximum of 999 entries."

It looks like the same limit apply to the web site as well.

You could try to add [custom query parameters for the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters) to limit the amount of results you get, like for example:

- caption=true|false
- duration=short|medium|long
- format=1|5|6
- time=today|this_week|this_month (instead of the default: all_time)

This way you can use a combination of queries to get more of the results that you're interested in.

**Edit**: While searching how to use the duration, I came across [YouTube GData API - Query for videos with a specific duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482203/youtube-gdata-api-query-for-videos-with-a-specific-duration?rq=1) on Stack Overflow, which refers to [YouTube API v2.0 – Retrieving a Partial Response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial). You can for example specify a maximum view count (which might be useful to get the Long Tail) using this experimental "Retrieving a Partial Response API" and that's only one of the many things you can do with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The custom query parameters can indeed help me a bit with my studies!

Comment: Yep I came across the partial feed response. The problem is that it seems to filter the original requested feed only. So when I for example search for the keyword "sports" and I usually get 1000results and now I use the partial feed response method to only show me e.g. all videos < 500.000 views it shows me just 2 entries (just as an example). it seems not to create a completely new feed, instead it just filters the original requested. If there is another way I maybe haven't thought about, please let me know. If it would work to create a completely new response feed my problem would be solved.